# C++ Structure with Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, structure, bubble-sort

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios Express 2012, and I am trying to write a program that gets the rainfall per month and displays it. I have to use structures, and I have to use bubble sort to display it from largest to smallest. I seem to have become lost in my code, and I'm confused with where I went wrong. It is currently telling me I have two unresolved externals.

```
//This program shows the months of the year with their associated rainfall amount.
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 12;

struct Rainfall
{
double rain[SIZE];

double getValue()
{
    double value = rain[SIZE];
    return value;
}

};

struct Months
{
const string MONTHS[SIZE];

Months()
{
    string MONTHS[SIZE] = {"January", "Feburary", "March",
                         "April", "May", "June", "July", 
                         "August","September","October",
                         "November","December"};
}

string getNames()
{
    string names = MONTHS[SIZE];
    return names;
}
};

//Function Prototypes
double getInput(const Months &, Rainfall &);
void sortData(Rainfall[],int);
void displayData(const Months, const Rainfall &);

int main()
{
Months timePeriod;
Rainfall amount;
Rainfall rain[SIZE];

getInput(timePeriod,amount);
sortData(rain,SIZE);
displayData(timePeriod,amount);

cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

/*****getInput*****/
double getInput(Months &timePeriod, Rainfall &amount)
{
cout << "\nPlease enter the amount of rainfall per month for the following  months:\n";

for(int counter = 0; counter <= 11; counter++)
{
    cout << timePeriod.MONTHS[counter] << ": ";
    cin >> amount.rain[counter];
    cout << endl;
    return amount.rain[counter];
}

}

/*****sortData*****/
void sortData(Rainfall array[], int SIZE)
{
Rainfall temp;
bool swap;

do
{
    swap = false;
    for(int count = 0; count < (SIZE-1); count++)
    {
        if(array[count].getValue() > array[count +1].getValue())
        {
            temp = array[count];
            array[count] = array[count +1];
            array[count + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
} while (swap);
}

/*****displayData*****/
void displayData(Rainfall number[], Months names[], int SIZE)
{
for(int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    cout << names[index].getNames() << endl;
    cout << number[index].getValue() << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: could you put the Linker errors (unresolved externals)?

Comment: This `double value = rain[SIZE];` indexes past the end of the array.  The `getNames` function is also incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your definitions match your declarations.

```
double getInput(const Months &, Rainfall &);
void sortData(Rainfall[],int);
void displayData(const Months, const Rainfall &);
```

Without looking at all of them I can see a discrepancy here with `displayData`

```
void displayData(const Months, const Rainfall &); // Declaration.
void displayData(Rainfall number[], Months names[], int SIZE) // Definition.
```

An **unresolved external symbol** in this case means that you have *declared* a function, but during the linking stage there was no *definition* found for it.

You have declared the `displayData` function to take a `const Months&` and `const Rainfall&` argument. Your definition takes a `Rainfall[]`, `Months[]` and `int` argument. These therefore, are not matching, and to the compiler they are different functions.

Thanks to function overloading, we can have functions with the same name but take different arguments.

Comment: Okay, so I've fixed those to match. Not sure what I was doing there. ;) My problem is now this part "int main()
{
Months timePeriod;
Rainfall amount;
Rainfall rain[SIZE];

Comment: My question being, I'm not sure what this part actually does, or how it needs to be. Textbook doesn't really seem to explain it.

Comment: I've made some edits, maybe that will help understand it more.

Answer (score 2):

Running on `VS2010`, you have the below Linker errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl displayData(struct Months,struct Rainfall const &)" (?displayData@@YAXUMonths@@ABURainfall@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl getInput(struct Months const &,struct Rainfall &)" (?getInput@@YANABUMonths@@AAURainfall@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Meaning that you need to match the declaration and definition for the 2 functions (your parameters are not the same):

```
1. displayData
2. getInput
```